# Creating queries through loops and checking wether row exists or else insert

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a list of a list in Python which I'm trying to either insert or update to Postgresql. I've tried both for-loops and while-loops but it gets messy when I'm trying to check wether the user already exists in postgres. I want to loop through the list of lists and insert/update every user in postgres.

I have below variables, which way would you recommend me to choose? My last shot was the if exists, which does not work with postgres..

```
userList = [user1, user2, user3]
i=0 
while ( i < len(userList)):
    query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = '" + userList[i][2] + "') INSERT INTO login (created, username, password, email) VALUES (NOW(), '" + userList[i][0] + "','" + userList[i][1] + "','" + userList[i][2] + "')"
    i += 1
    settings.database_connection.execute_sql(query)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `for user in user_list`. What are you using to connect to the db?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How is the connection to the DB relevant?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy, because there is a little thing called documentation that usually shows you exactly what you want to know or is documentation also not relevant?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Nobody was talking about any documentation. I was asking you how's method of connecting to the DB related to his question.

Comment: @SLI Ildar's answer is a better solution, but (if you have for example older PostgreSQL) you can also simply split it to 2 separate queries: first will do just select, then check if it returned anything in Python and depending on the result execute insert or update.

Answer (score 0):

There is new feature (so called UPSERT) in PostgreSQL 9.5. So you can either insert or update a row:

```
INSERT INTO login VALUES (<your values>)
ON CONFLICT(email) DO UPDATE SET password=..., email=...;
```

More details in official documentation: [PostgreSQL 9.5.1 Documentation: INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html)